# Replace a character in a BufferedWriter

Tags: java, string, text, bufferedwriter

I am creating a text file using `BufferedWriter`

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = 
           new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/temp.txt"));

/*

     Add Contents using bufferedWriter.write()

*/
```

At certain places while adding contents I add a string sequence **######**

Before I do `bufferedWriter.close()` I want to replace the **######** sequence with some specific value.

How can I do that?

I do not want to re-open the Writer, but could use a different writer if it allows this to be done.

Comment: Why do you write it if you're just going to replace it? Is it like a template?

Comment: See [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The value that has to be replaced is only known after certain calculations and only once the contents are put in.

Answer (score 2):

Create the contents as a `String` or a `List<String>`.

After you replace the `#####`, you write the `String` or `List<String>` to the `BufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the following options:

- Write your own `Writer`. None of the `Writers` I know about are able to do this simply because they actually *write* to disk (into the file) when you call `.write()` on them. Some, like `BufferedWriter`, don't do it immediatelly, but if you exceed the inner buffer, it will be flushed into the file anyway - even without you calling `flush()` or `close()`.
- Simply use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Write to a `StringBuilder`, then replace your sequence and only then write to a file.
- Write to a new file every time you encounter `######`. Effectively, you'll have several files with a missing piece of text in between them. After you know the right sequence that should replace `######`, join the files using that sequence.
- If you have enough memory to hold all the data in memory, use a `List<String>` (split at the `######`, then join the elements using something like a [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)).

Answer (score -1):

What about something like that ?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/temp.txt"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/user/temp.txt"))
String line
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()
while (line = br.readLine()) {
    line = line.replace("######", "yourReplacement")
    sb.append(line)
}
br.close()
bw.write(sb.toString(), 0, sb.length())
bw.close()
```